# How to appear User's name instead of Login ID in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I use Staff ID (username) to logged into the system, however I want to view my Name (name) instead of my Staff ID when successfully logged in. I have tried to change PHP script parameter from "username" to "name", unfortunately failed and error.

Here I share the script.

**PHP Script for Login Page**

```
// Validate credentials
        if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

 // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                        // Bind result variables
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                            if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                                // Password is correct, so start a new session
                                session_start();

                                // Store data in session variables
                                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                                $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
```

**HTML Code for Login Page**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <div class="input-group custom input-group-lg" <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Staff ID" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
    <span style="color:#FF0500" class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
```

**Main Page**

```
<span class="user-name">Welcome, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b></span>
```

Comment: Step 1: Select the name in the query. `$sql = "SELECT id, name, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";` the rest shoudl be fairly obvious

Comment: In your $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, name FROM users WHERE username = ?"; and then modify your SESSION

Comment: Thank You RiggsFolly & Sfili_81. finnaly it success.

Answer (score 0):

This answer solve my question above:

```
// Prepare a select statement
$sql = "SELECT id, name, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

// Bind result variables
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $name, $username, $hashed_password);

// Store data in session variables
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
```